# Accent marks are not sent properly in email

Tags: html

I’m having a problem sending emails with accented characters using `MimeKit`. I hope that a little of the VB.NET code will explain.

The email message is formatted for HTML and contains the text: 
`“à été enregistré”`. This is stored in a variable called `strMessage`.

These lines of code pertaining to the email body follow:

```
Dim objSMTPMsg As New MimeMessage 
Dim builder = New BodyBuilder()
builder.HtmlBody = strMessage
```

So far the accented characters are OK. But when I execute this line

```
objSMTPMsg.Body = builder.ToMessageBody()
```

`objSMTPMsg.Body` contains this text:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" & vbCrLf & "Content-Id: <0JA01KW5N4U4.WYNQY1DO7ACJ@DEV-04A>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"">" & vbCrLf & "<html xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office""><head>" & vbCrLf & "<meta content=""text/html; charset=unicode"" http-equiv=""Content-Type"" />" & vbCrLf & "<style id=""page_style""></style>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "<style><!-- #token {color:#ff8040;} --></style>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "</head>" & vbCrLf & "<body style=""font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; color: black"" selectionpending=""true""><span style=""font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; color: black"">&nbsp;Votre incident " & vbCrLf & "Ã  Ã©tÃ© enregistrÃ© dans notre systÃ¨me de traitement</span></body></html>
```

`“à été enregistré”` was changed to `"Ã  Ã©tÃ© enregistrÃ©"`.

Depending on the encoding used when it is mailed, the text where the accented characters had been show up as question marks or as they appear here. The accented characters are gone.

I found one post on this but the the person who supplied line of code to fix it did not specify where to put it or what object it was part of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I found one post on this but the the person who supplied line of code to fix it did not specify where to put it or what object it was part of."* - I'd suggest sharing the link. Some of us may not know the answer off the top of our head, but given that other answer, perhaps we could provide the context necessary to utilize it in your specific case.